# Design database capable of searching for rows where all items in a column are in a given list

Tags: database-design

I'm designing a mobile app that will utilise some sort of database with the primary search functionality requiring every element in a list of items in the table to exist in a given list used for searching.

Given the below example table for simplicty:

| ID | Owner | Pets |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sharon | [Dog, Cat, Rabbit] |
| 2 | James | [Cat, Turtle] |
| 3 | Natalie | [Dog, Fish, Rabbit] |

and the list [Dog,Cat,Hamster,Rabbit,Turtle]

1. [Dog,Cat,Rabbit] all exist in [Dog,Cat,Hamster,Rabbit,Turtle].
2. [Cat, Turtle] all exist in [Dog,Cat,Hamster,Rabbit,Turtle].
3. [Dog,Fish,Rabbit] do not all exist in [Dog,Cat,Hamster,Rabbit,Turtle].

So row 1 and 2 should be returned, but not 3.

I've looked into using an inverted index, which seems useful for returning rows that contain a certain item (e.g. Dog), but I'm not sure if it's capable of checking if all items exist in the search list.

There are approximately 700 unique items (Pets in this example), and 10,000 rows of data (which will increase in time)

I'm looking for a logical design.

Any help would be appreciated.